# Changing the size of cells in grid view?

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview

I have a gridview in Android which is populated by a custom view which inherits from imagebuttons.

What I would like to do is modify the size of the imagebuttons inside the gridview as well as their padding between cells.

Here is my `getView()` code. I've tried using layouts but can't because I don't have access to the parent view.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (image == null)
        image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.dollar);

    ExpenseIcon ic = new ExpenseIcon(context);
    ic.setImageBitmap(image);

    return ic;
}
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the with with [`setColumnWidth(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setColumnWidth%28int%29) or set the column count by calling [`setNumColumns(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setNumColumns%28int%29) depending on what you extactly trying. By the way you can also set that values by xml ([`android:columnWidth`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android%3acolumnWidth) and [`android:numColumns`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android%3anumColumns)).

For the spacing you can use [`android:horizontalSpacing`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android%3ahorizontalSpacing) or [`setHorizontalSpacing(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setHorizontalSpacing%28int%29) and [`android:verticalSpacing`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android%3averticalSpacing) or [`setVerticalSpacing(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setVerticalSpacing%28int%29).

For controling the highe you need to change your `getView` function:

```
public YourConstructor() {
    // inflater should be a private member variable
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context
                   .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    // other code...
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        // create new one and put it into convertView. e.g.:
        convertView = new ExpenseIcon(context);
        AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(HEIGHT,WIDTH);
        convertView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }

    // set the image to the currient convertView. e.g.:
    ((ExpenseIcon)convertView).setImageBitmap(image);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: The hight can be simply controled in your adapter. I would suggest to do that in the [`getView(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) function. There you can set the hight by overriding the layout params of the `convertView`.

Comment: I've been trying to figure it out there but haven't managed to do it, I've updated my question with some source code...

Comment: Oh no that doesn't look good for performance reasons you should ever use the convertView. I'll make an edit of my answer...

Comment: I tried adding my own linearparam like so:

LinearLayout.LayoutParams l = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, 30);
   convertView.setLayoutParams(l);

But then got an exception thrown after the fucntion finishd executing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29028/discussion-between-rekire-and-meds)

Answer (score 1):

Create an XML and inflate.I gave sample to use in getview...Set imagesize in the layout..

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
                holder.image.setImageResource(list.get(position).getIconid());

                return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
                ImageView image;
                  }
```

Comment: Using ViewViewholder is always a good idea, but your implementation does not use it.