# Dimensions of the GridView cell is not changing

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview, getview

I dont know what is the problem in my code. I want to display some images in a GridView but the images being displayed are very small, and same is happening with the high resolutions images too. Please help. Thanks in Advance.

I dont know what to do. I am posting my code too.

activity_main.xml file

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview_stickers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center">

</GridView>
```

gridview_items.xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#000000">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/sticker"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
/>
```

getView method of the AdapterClass

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View imageView  = convertView;
    ImageView picture;


    if(imageView == null) {
        imageView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_items, parent, false);
        imageView.setTag(R.id.sticker, imageView.findViewById(R.id.sticker));
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

    }
        picture = (ImageView)imageView.getTag(R.id.sticker);
        picture.setImageBitmap(img.get(position).imageBitmap);

     return imageView;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251569/changing-the-size-of-cells-in-grid-view

Comment: i have visited this page and tried also, didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out myself. I changed the

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
```

to

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 300));
```

and I got the desired results.